# Replace ultra-dynamic.xml with ultra-custom.xml in ultraesb 3.2.0

Tags: xml, intellij-idea, esb, ultraesb, adroitlogic

I watched youtube ultraesb1.0.1 demo with IntelliJ CE9 contains ultra-dynamic.xml may be replaced by ultra-custom.xml in ultraesb 3.2.0.

```
ultra-custom.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:u="http://www.adroitlogic.org/ultraesb"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.adroitlogic.org/ultraesb http://schemas.ultraesb.org/ultraesb-2.0.xsd">

    <u:endpoint id="echo-service">
        <u:address>http://localhost:9000/service/EchoService</u:address>
    </u:endpoint>

    <u:sequence id="error-handler">
        <u:java><![CDATA[
            logger.error("Custom error handler : " + msg.getLastException().toString());
        ]]></u:java>
    </u:sequence>


    <u:proxy id="health-check">
        <u:transport id="http-8280"/>
        <u:transport id="https-8443"/>
        <u:target>
            <u:inSequence>
                <u:java><![CDATA[
                    msg = msg.createDefaultResponseMessage();
                    mediation.sendResponse(msg,org.adroitlogic.ultraesb.api.management.
                        ServerAdminImpl.getInstance().getUserDefinedStatusCode());
                ]]></u:java>
            </u:inSequence>
        </u:target>
    </u:proxy>

</beans>
```

While I can't find ultra-dynamics.xml on internet anywhere so that I follow ultraesb 1.0.1 demo from youtube for my initial smooth output. Further I noticed that ultra-custom.xml contains separate stand alone tags while ultra-dynamics.xml has everything under

Can anyone help please

Comment: What video?  What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 5):

UltraESB architecture has been changed and the ultra-dynamic.xml file is no more supported, you should be writing a deployment-unit instead of the ultra-dynamic.xml file.

You may refer to the new architecture in brief under our documentation;

http://docs.adroitlogic.org/display/esb/Overall+Architecture+of+UltraESB

Please note that there is a deployment unit maven plugin that you can use to build a deployment unit, and an archetype that will create a sample deployment unit to get started with.

Use the following command to generate a sample project and place your ultra-dynamic.xml configuration in the ultra-unit.xml file of the generated deployment unit.

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.adroitlogic.tooling.maven -DarchetypeArtifactId=ultraesb-deployment-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=2.3.0 -DarchetypeRepository=http://repository.adroitlogic.org/maven2 -DgroupId=com.acme.esb -DartifactId=test-du -Dversion=1.0
```

Now you can build the deployment unit with "mvn clean install" command and place the generated artifact (from the target directory) into the conf/deployments directory of the UltraESB installation.

Hope this helps!